# Como publicar arquivos de imagem usando Firebase Storage em modo offline?

Tags: java, firebase

Olá,
Estou desenvolvendo um código dentro do Android Studio que permita o cadastro de dados num formulário com campos texto e um arquivo de imagem de modo offline (celular sem nenhuma conexão com internet). Funciona muito bem com 
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` mas com o `FirebaseStorage.getInstance()`, ou seja, com os dois juntos, (texto e imagem) ocorrem erros.

a idéia é salvar os dados (textos e sua imagem em anexo) localmente no Smartphone (inclusive consultar) e quando o mesmo se conectar em alguma rede de internet o mesmo sincronizar os dados no servidor do Firebase.

Fiz testes usando apenas textos e funciona muito bem, mas se tiro uma foto e anexo a mesma no formulário, nada acontece.

Alguma sugestão? Alguém já enfrentou algum problema similar a este?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //
        mFirebaseData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseData.getReference("Data");
        mDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);
        //storage
        mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Salve suas imagens usando banco de dados local e use a biblioteca Workmanager que trabalha em background para sincronizar com o firebase quando houver internet disponível.

Comment: Certo, muito grato pela dica.Algum exemplo de implementação disso? link com exemplos ou documentação talvez?

Comment: Sim meu amigo.... de uma olhadinha neste vídeo para você poder entrar no assunto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3DO1MRN89M

Comment: Depois você pode buscar por mais exemplos....

Comment: Vou olhar sim, obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai um exemplo prático do que você perguntou:

Nesse exemplo, vamos fazer o upload de uma imagem para o `FirebaseStorage`. Para isso, suponho que os passos para aquisição da imagem via camera ou galeria seja conhecida antecipadamente.

Você pode iniciar background thread a partir de um botão:

```
     saveStoreData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isFormFieldsFilled()) {

                DocumentReference docRef = DatabaseRouter.getStoresCollectionRef().document();
                String key = docRef.getId();

                // Create a Constraints object that defines when the task should run
                Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build();

                // Passing data to the worker class
                Data.Builder builder = new Data.Builder();
                builder.putString("image_uri", profileImageUri.toString());
                builder.putString("image_pushkey", key);
                Data inputData = builder.build();

                // ...then create a OneTimeWorkRequest that uses those constraints
                OneTimeWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                        .Builder(UploadImageToServerWorker.class)
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .setInputData(inputData)
                        .build();

                // Execute and Manage the background service
                WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(getActivity());
                workManager.enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);

            }

        }
    });
```

Agora é só criar a classe Worker: **UploadImageToServerWorker**

```
public class UploadImageToServerWorker extends Worker {

    // https://www.raywenderlich.com/6040-workmanager-tutorial-for-android-getting-started

    private static final String TAG = "debinf UploadWorker";

    public UploadImageToServerWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        String imageUriInput = getInputData().getString("image_uri");
        String imagePushKey = getInputData().getString("image_pushkey");
        Log.i(TAG, "doWork: BACKGROUND WORK STARTED FOR KEY: "+imagePushKey);

        final Result[] result = {Result.retry()};
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        StorageReference storageRef = DatabaseRouter.getStoresStorageRef(imagePushKey).child(imagePushKey+".jpg");
        storageRef.putFile(Uri.parse(imageUriInput)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: image uploaded successfuly!");
                    result[0] = Result.success();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: image NOT uploaded - RETRYING");
                    result[0] = Result.retry();
                }
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result[0];
    }
}
```

Pronto! Não sei se esse é o método mais apropriado, mas dá conta do serviço.

"Problemas" que eu encontrei:

1) O envio da imagem é feito sem conexão com a internet, mas a conexão com a internet é reestabelecida **antes** do tempo limite de conexão com `FirebaseStorage`: **O método `doWork()` é executado 2 vezes.**

2) O envio da imagem é feito sem conexão com a internet e a conexão com a internet é reestabelecida **depois** do tempo limite de conexão com `FirebaseStorage`: **O médoto `doWork()` não é executado assim que a internet retorna.**

Bem... Espero ter ajudado e boa sorte!